# Python LAB - Exact Change (Functions)

Tags: python

Thank you for the advice. I edited the program and tried to run my code and it produces no output. Can someone please let me know what I missed?
Thanks for the help in advance, I am very new to this and still trying to understand.

DIRECTIONS
Define a function called exact_change that takes the total change amount in cents and calculates the change using the fewest coins. The coin types are pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters. Then write a main program that reads the total change amount as an integer input, calls exact_change(), and outputs the change, one coin type per line. Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies. Output "no change" if the input is 0 or less.

Ex: If the input is:

0
(or less), the output is:

no change
Ex: If the input is:

45
the output is:

2 dimes
1 quarter

Your program must define and call the following function. The function exact_change() should return num_pennies, num_nickels, num_dimes, and num_quarters.
def exact_change(user_total)

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    return(num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickles, num_pennies)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    
    input_val = float(input())
    num_dollars = input_val // 100 
    rem=input_val % 100
    num_quarters = rem // 25
    rem = rem % 25
    num_dimes = rem // 10
    rem = rem % 10
    num_nickles = rem // 5
    rem = rem % 5
    num_pennies = rem
    
    if input_val <= 0:
        print("no change")
    else:
        num_pennies = rem
        conv_penny = str(int(num_pennies))
        rem = rem % 1
        if num_pennies == 1:
            print(conv_penny + ' penny')
        elif num_pennies > 1:
            print(conv_penny + ' pennies')
            
        num_nickels = rem // 5
        conv_nickel = str(int(num_nickels))
        rem = rem % 5
        if num_nickels == 1:
            print(conv_nickel + ' nickel')
        elif num_nickels > 1:
            print(conv_nickel + ' nickels')
            
        num_dimes = rem // 10
        conv_dime = str(int(num_dimes))
        rem = rem % 10
        if num_dimes == 1:
            print(conv_dime + ' dime')
        elif num_dimes > 1:
            print(conv_dime + ' dimes')
        
        num_quarters = rem // 25
        conv_quarter = str(int(num_quarters))
        rem = rem % 25
        if num_quarters == 1:
            print(conv_quarter + ' quarter')
        elif num_quarters > 1:
            print(conv_quarter + ' quarters')
            
        num_dollars = input_val // 100
        conv_dollar = str(int(num_dollars))
        rem = input_val % 100
        if num_dollars == 1:
            print(conv_dollar + ' dollar')
        elif num_dollars > 1:
            print(conv_dollar + ' dollars')
```

Comment: You have repeated the first section of code

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. If there is a problem with your code, clearly state what that problem is.